# Esxi 6.5 Server, Can't connect to web server of ESXI, can only reach KVM console

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

When trying to connect to my ESXI 6.5 server via vSphere client it fails to connect, when I try to connect via web browser using the static IP I assigned it, it just connects me to the KVM. I can ping the Servers IP ok.

Comment: You can't connect to an ESXi 6.5 host with the GUI client, if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Agreed, you can't connect with the c# client anymore. If it's taking you to the KVM, you may have set your ESXi management address and KVM address to be the same. Consider changing to a different address.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a conflicting IP. Try assigning the ESX server a different address if you can, then run a network test from the console to make sure your server can reach the gateway etc.